# Jdeveloper 12c Ide Dark Theme

Tags: themes, jdeveloper

Im moving from Jdev 11g to 12c and had a dark theme on 11g. When i moved to 12c I can no longer find a drop down to change the theme to from the white default. Was able to set the code syntax to custom color scheme but cant find a way to change window colors. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Shudown JDEV

```
% cd $ORACLE_HOME/jdeveloper/ide/themes
% cp fusionblue.jar fusionblue.jar.bak
% jar xvf  fuserblue.jar META-INF/themes.properties
```

**Edit themes.properties and chanche color codes as you like **

```
% jar uvf  fusionblue.jar META-INF/themes.properties
```

Start your JDEV.

NOTE: This is not an official method, please update this if you know one.

> OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION: You can find instructions on how to create a
>   'CODE' theme at $JDEV_HOME/ide/themes/creating_themes.html